# Fill the blank type of text in non exam document

Tags: exam, article

I want to make a fill the blank type of text in a non-exam document. Here the desired result that I want:

```
Let A be a subset of R, A called measurable set if m*(...) = ........, for all .... in R
```

I know that it can be accomplished by using examdesign class. But I don't want to use another class just for this task.

Here my attempt to create the example above.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
Let $A$ be a subset of $\mathbf{R}$, $A$ called measurable set
if $m^*(\ldots) = \ldots \ldots \ldots, 
\text{ for all } \ldots \ldots \text{ in } \mathbf{R}$.
\end{document}
```

But the solution that I want is using something like `\blank{some text}` that will be substituted with dots.

Extra: the dots must longer than the substituted text.

Hence, I can write:

```
if $m^*(\blank{B}) = \blank{m^*(A \cap B) + m^*(A \cap B^c)}
\text{ for all } \blank{B} \text{ in } \mathbf{R}$.
```

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: and would you like the 'blanked' letters to appear when showing solutions?

Answer (score 4):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\def\blank#1{\setbox0\hbox{$#1$}\hbox to \wd0{\dotfill}}

\begin{document}

if $m^*(\blank{B}) = \blank{m^*(A \cap B) + m^*(A \cap B^c)}
\text{ for all } \blank{B} \text{ in } \mathbf{R}$.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The command `\mdotfill` draws some dotted line that has a width equal to the width of its argument plus `1em` (as was required in the question); using the optional argument, you can increase the extra length by a desired amount:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\mes}{m}

\newlength\mylen
\newcommand\mdotfill[2][1em]{%
  \settowidth\mylen{$#2$}
  \addtolength\mylen{#1}
  \leavevmode\hbox to \mylen{\xleaders\hbox{.}\hfill}}

\begin{document}

$\mes^*(A \cap B) + \mes^*(A \cap B^c)$

\mdotfill{\mes^*(A \cap B) + \mes^*(A \cap B^c)}

\mdotfill[2em]{\mes^*(A \cap B) + \mes^*(A \cap B^c)}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm partial to readability' `;)`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newlength{\blankwidth}
\newcommand{\blank}[1]{%
  \ifmmode\settowidth{\blankwidth}{\ensuremath{{#1}{#1}{#1}}}%
  \else\settowidth{\blankwidth}{{#1}{#1}{#1}}%
  \fi
  \makebox[\blankwidth]{\dotfill}}

\begin{document}
if $m^*(\blank{B}) = \blank{m^*(A \cap B)} + m^*(A \cap B^c)
\text{ for all } \blank{B} \text{ in } \mathbf{R}$.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Also note that this require *no* extra packages.

Answer (score 1):

I modified some commands from the `censor` package, using underlining, instead of dots.   I modified my answer so that the `\censor` command is for arguments in text mode and the `\censor*` command is for arguments in math mode.  The rule denote by `\extra` (currently 1ex long) is the length added to the argument that you requested.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pbox}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\def\extra{\rule{1ex}{0ex}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\censor{\@ifstar{\@cenmath}{\@centext}}
  \newcommand\@cenmath[1]{%
              \protect\rule[-.3ex]{\widthofpbox{\extra$#1$}}{0.1ex}}
  \newcommand\@centext[1]{%
              \protect\rule[-.3ex]{\widthofpbox{\extra#1}}{0.1ex}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

The answer is 1ex longer than \censor{forty two}.

if $m^*(\censor*{B}) = \censor*{m^*(A \cap B) + m^*(A \cap B^c)}
\text{ for all } \censor*{B} \text{ in }
\mathbf{R}$.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This should be enough: `\def\blank{\makebox[2cm]{\dotfill}}`. Usage: `$A$ \blank $B$`. I think that more space, then originally, is needed, so the suggested difference. The other version: `\def\blank#1{\makebox[#1]{\dotfill}}`.