# dotfill for length of text

Tags: lengths

I am trying to make some small dotted lines for the signature of different persons, with their printed names just below. I thought it would look great if the width and horizontal placement of the dotted line matched the names of the persons. I have looked for a solution, and found one which [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110481/fill-the-blank-type-of-text-in-non-exam-document/110489#110489), and is included in my example.

However, this does not alter the spacing, so that it doesn't really match the length perfectly. Is there a good way to accomplish this?

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\address{Street \\ City \\ Country}

\newlength\mylen
\newcommand\mdotfill[2][-0em]{%
  \settowidth\mylen{$#2$}
  \addtolength\mylen{#1}
  \leavevmode\hbox to \mylen{\xleaders\hbox{.}\hfill}}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Company name \\ Street\\ City\\ Country}
\opening{Dear Sir or Madam:}
\lipsum[1-2]
\vfill
\closing{Signed,}

\mdotfill{John Doe}\hfill\mdotfill{Jane Doe} \hfill \mdotfill{Joe W. Long Name} \hfill \mdotfill{Lisa Simpson}\\
John Doe\hfill Jane Doe\hfill Joe W. Long Name\hfill Lisa Simpson

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a macro that prints the dots and the name underneath, based on the small package `makebox`:

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\address{Street \\ City \\ Country}
\usepackage{makebox}
\newcommand\signhere[1] {\begin{tabular}{c}\makebox*{#1}{\xleaders\hbox{.}\hfill}\\[2ex]#1\end{tabular}}

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{Company name \\ Street\\ City\\ Country}
  \opening{Dear Sir or Madam:}
  \lipsum[1-2]
  \vfill
  \closing{Signed,}
  \signhere{Edward Lear}\hfill\signhere{Jane Eyre}\hfill\signhere{Mahatma Kane Jeeves}\hfill\signhere{Lisa Simpson}

\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great. I should have thought about using a tabular, really.